# How to solve Uncaught ReferenceError: bus is not defined? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I follow this tutorial : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

It to passing data from a component to other component

See my case below. I try like that

My view is like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <search-filter-view ...></search-filter-view>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <search-result-view ...></search-result-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

My search-filter-view component is like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:[...],
        data(){
            return{
                ...
            }
        },
        methods:{
            filterBySort: function (sort){
                bus.$emit('sort-param', sort)
                this.sort = sort
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My search-result-view component is like this :

```
<script>
    export default {
        props:[...],
        data() {
            return {
                ...
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getVueItems: function(page) {
                bus.$on('sort-param', function (sort) {
                    console.log(sort);
                })
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I add `var bus = new Vue();` on \resources\assests\js\app.js

So it can be accessed anywhere

I want display value of sort parameter (filterBySort method, component one) to getVueItems method (component two)

When executed, in the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bus is not defined

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to to export the variable bus from the `App.vue` and import it where ever you need it.

What I personally do is I create a dedicated file for it: **bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

and import it like this where it is needed:

```
import bus from 'path/of/bus'
<script>
    export default{
        props:[...],
        data(){
            return{
                ...
            }
        },
        methods:{
            filterBySort: function (sort){
                bus.$emit('sort-param', sort)
                this.sort = sort
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What about listening for the event?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your code which defines the variable, `var bus = new Vue();`, gets executed before the code that uses this variable.

Also, make sure that the bus variable is accessible by the code that uses it.