# Uncaught ReferenceError: Bus is not defined in Spark Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-spark

I was trying to move the some functionality which is the Drop down of the Laravel Spark at the NavBar to my app.blade.php .

my code looks like this

```
<body class="skin-1">

  <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div  id="spark-app" v-cloak>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        @include('layouts.wf_navigation')

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

            <!-- Main view  -->
            @yield('content')



            <!-- Footer -->
            @include('layouts.footer')

        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->

    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
@show
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

but I am getting an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Bus is not defined

the error is referencing to this line of code in APp.js

```
  Bus.$on('updateUser', function () {
            self.getUser();
        })
```

**UPDATE**

The Bus variable is defined in the App.js itself the code looks like this

```
if (window.Vue === undefined) {
  window.Vue = __webpack_require__(287);

  window.Bus = new Vue();
}
```

**note:** the previous issue got fixed by removing the the extra Vuejs file which was included in the top of my app.blade.php

**Update 1**
There is new error

> [Vue warn]: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state
>   to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates,
>   such as .

the templates which are being included are

wf_navigation.blade.php

```
<div class="row border-bottom">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" method="post" action="/">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for something..." class="form-control" name="top-search" id="top-search" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">


        <?php $currentTeam = auth()->user()->currentTeam; ?>

        @if($currentTeam)
        <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ $currentTeam->name }}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/settings/teams/{{$currentTeam->id}}#/owner">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/settings/teams/{{$currentTeam->id}}#/membership">Members</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/settings/teams/{{$currentTeam->id}}#/subscription">Subscription</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/settings/teams/{{$currentTeam->id}}#/invoices">Invoices</a>
                </li>

                @include('spark::nav.teams')

            </ul>
        </li>
        @endif

        </ul>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Which is calling @include('spark::nav.teams')

the teams.blade.php looks like this

```
<li class="dropdown-header">{{ ucfirst(str_plural(Spark::teamString())) }}</li>

<!-- Create Team -->
@if (Spark::createsAdditionalTeams())
    <li>
        <a href="/settings#/{{str_plural(Spark::teamString())}}">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-btn fa-plus"></i>Create {{ ucfirst(Spark::teamString()) }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endif

<!-- Switch Current Team -->
@if (Spark::showsTeamSwitcher())
    <li v-for="team in teams">
        <a :href="'/{{ str_plural(Spark::teamString()) }}/'+ team.id +'/switch'">
            <span v-if="user.current_team_id == team.id">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-btn fa-check text-success"></i>@{{ team.name }}
            </span>

            <span v-else>
                <img :src="team.photo_url" class="spark-team-photo-xs"><i class="fa fa-btn"></i>@{{ team.name }}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
@endif

<li class="divider"></li>
```

'footer.blade.php'

`<div class="footer">
    <div class="pull-right">
        V4.0
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Powered By</strong> Energy Engine &copy; 2010-2017
    </div>
</div>`

I am new to vue so no idea whats happening there

Comment: Where is `Bus` defined, Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42288465/1610034) helps.

Comment: @Saurabh no that does not help I already went through it . I am updating the question, I just updated

Comment: @Saurabh that issue got fixed I was calling Vue js two times actually one from the cdn and one is already in the package of Spark.

Comment: @Saurabh I am getting this error now `[Vue warn]: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>. `

Comment: Can you add relevant Template code, as the error says, you may have included few <script> tags inside vue component template.

Comment: @Saurabh I am updating my question with some more explaination about the templates being includedd

Comment: @Saurabh kindly have a look specifically to teams.blade.php since that's the file im including to my wf_topnavbar.blade.php